# What is wrong in this C++ code snippet with template<class Vector>

Tags: c++

Here I am just using test() function and passing vector to it. 
in test function using decltype() to deduce the type but output is completely mysterious.

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

template<class Vector>
void test(Vector& vec)
{
    using E = decltype(vec[0]);
    for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i) {
        vec.push_back(E(i));
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<double> v;
    test(v);
    for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("%f\n", v[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be less mysterious than "output is completely mysterious".

Answer (score 2):

`E` is `double&`, not `double`, as shown when you change the `push_back` line to

```
vec.push_back(static_cast<E>(i));
```

"error: invalid static_cast from type ‘int’ to type ‘E’ {aka ‘double&’}"

Because of this, you are actually modifying the internal representation of `double`, as if you were using `reinterpret_cast`. You should use `static_cast` to convert between values.

Use either of these definitions instead:

```
using E = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(vec.at(0))>;
using E = typename Vector::value_type;
```